# How do I load scene using scene manager build index in the build setting unity3d

Tags: unity, c#, scenemanager

I only got one scene to load when the timer reaches zero; I need one more scene to load. The scene manager builder index is not working for me. I have tried `Application.Load()` and `SceneManager.Load()`, but nothing works.

I can only reload the other scene with the following line of code, but it reloads the current scene, and I don't want it to do that.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

The scene I am trying to reload is my restart. It's suppose to load the scene I have set up in the build settings. It's also suppose to load when the timer reaches a set time, and does that, but only with the previous line of code.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public MyClockScript myClock; 
    public ScoreManagerScript scoremanager; 
    public int scoreToReach = 99; // change this value to what you want 
    public string nextScene = "FY"; // change this value to what you want

    void Update () 
     {
       if (myClock.m_leftTime <= 0)
       {
         if ((ScoreManagerScript.score >= scoreToReach) && (nextScene != ""))
         {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);
         }
         else
         {
           int gy = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
         }
       }
     }
 }
```

Help would be appreciated. I have a picture of what I scene I want to load, too.

[image: My build settings screen. The desired scene, scene "GY" or 2, is highlighted.]

Comment: If you provide the project to a user, who is able to find *problems* but reports "Even with the code as it is, I am able to load scenes FY and GY", *the exact problem you were reporting in the first place*, it is clear that you are not providing a clear sample that demonstrates the problem you are reporting. "Questions about debugging a problem must provide a minimal, complete, **verifiable example of the issue** so that readers can diagnose it without needing to guess, read all of your code, or engage in extensive back-and-forth dialog.".

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine. The only issue is at the bottom, where you have another `LoadScene()` which uses the index `2`. Even with the code as it is, I am able to load scenes "FY" and "GY".

```
void Update ()
{
    if (myClock.m_leftTime <= 0) 
    {       //checking if there is a next scene
        if ((ScoreManagerScript.score >= scoreToReach) &&
            (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex + 1 < 
                                   SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings)) 
        {
            //load scene with next scene index
            SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex + 1);
            // SceneManager.LoadScene (nextScene);
            Debug.Log ("We are inside next scene if");
        } 
        else 
        {
            //load scene with current scene index/general reload
            SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex);
        }

        //load scene with next scene index
        SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex + 2);
        // Because this last load scene doesn't have a condition statement,
        // the script loads index 1, and than index 2. 
    }
}
```

---

#### Unrelated issue with enemies

Also, when running the game ,there was an `out-of-range` on your `EnemiesSpawner.cs`. I fixed it by doing the below;

```
for (int spawnCount = 0; spawnCount > 20; spawnCount++)
{
            Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints [spawnPointIndex].position,
                                                   spawnPoints [spawnPointIndex].rotation);
}
```

In addition, you might want to randomize how the enemies are spawned, as every time I started the game they spawn at the same location. Game looks great, by the way! Good luck.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43981/discussion-on-answer-by-fredz0003-how-do-i-load-scene-using-scene-manager-build).